# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf: Joined Entity Object Returning as null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot framework with Hibernate and JPA, and Thymeleaf for the view element. I want to show related data from 2 different entities on the same HTML table on a page. However the object which should contain the data from my joined entity is returning as null.

**EDIT:** The root cause of the problem is that the query which is being executed is joining my two tables on the 2 primary keys rather than on the primary key of my MsgOrig table and the foreign key of my ReplyMessage table ("msgOrigID") as intended. Any idea how I can correct this?

Also, just to get this working I am trying to return all messages. However my ultimate aim is to only return messages sent by the logged-in user. Is there a JPA repository method which could be used for this purpose? Or should I write a custom query instead?

Entity Class for MsgOrig:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "messageoriginator")
public class MsgOrig {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "Date")
private String date;    

@Column(name = "MsgTime")
private String msgTime;

@Column(name = "message")
private String msg;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinColumn(name = "msgOrigID")  
private ReplyMessage reply;

//getters and setters
}
```

Entity Class for ReplyMessage:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "replymessage")
public class ReplyMessage {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "msgOrigID")
private int msgOrigId;

@Column(name = "Date")
private String date;    

@Column(name = "MsgTime")
private String msgTime;

@Column(name = "message")
private String msg;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="reply")
private MsgOrig msgOrig; 

//getters and setters
}
```

Controller Method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value={"/mymessages"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView messages(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("mymessages", messageService.listAllMessages());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Implementation Class For MessageService interface:

```
@Service("messageService")
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService{

@Autowired
private MessageRepository messageRepository;    

@Override
public List<MsgOrig> listAllMessages() {
    return messageRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

Repository class:

```
@Repository("messageRepository")
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<MsgOrig, Integer> {

@Query("SELECT t.email FROM MsgOrig t where t.id = :id") 
String findUsersEmail(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

Relevant section on Thymeleaf template (returns "NOT FOUND"):

```
<td th:text="${mymessages.reply != null ? mymessages.reply.msgTime : 'NOT FOUND'}"/>
```

Comment: Have you debuuged this? What does the listAllMessages() method return?

Comment: Yes - this method returns the expected data from the MsgOrig entity/table and some null values. Not returning any data from my ReplyMessage entity/table.  The query which is executed looks like it may be the root of the issue, I see from my debug logs that it is "select <values> from replymessage replymessage0_ left outer join messageoriginator messageoriginator0_ on replymessage0_.id = messageoriginator0_.id where replymessage0_.id=?"  This should be joining on the msgOrigID column in my replymessage table rather than the id column from that table as per my entity classes - any suggestions?